# Trying to implement gravity into a Javascript game

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I'm making a side scroller game in Javascript and need to implement gravity for my character. For example, the character needs to jump up, jump to the right or jump to the left, then gradually come down just by pressing and releasing the up arrow on its own, or with the left or right arrow keys. Here's my code so far:

```
var gameChar_x;       //refers to the characters x position
var gameChar_y;       //refers to the characters y position
var floorPos_y;       //refers to the y position of the floor
var isJumping = false;

function draw()

  if (isJumping == true && gameChar_y == floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y = gameChar_y - 9.8    //makes the character jump when on the floor
  }

  if (isJumping == false && gameChar_y != floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y = gameChar_y + 9.8    //makes the character come back down when 
    the up arrow key is released

function keyPressed()

  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW && gameChar_y == floorPos_y) {   //jump if character is on the floor
    isJumping = true;
  }

  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW && keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW) {
    isJumping = true;
  }

  if (keyCode == UP_ARROW && keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
    isJumping = true;
  }
```

What I'd like to happen is when the up arrow is pressed and released, the character jumps up and slowly comes back down to the ground by 1 pixel at a time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an interval to simulate the animation of the char dropping 1px every 100ms:

```
// Max height a character can jump
const MAX_JUMP_HEIGHT = 10;
// Current position of the character
let x_position = 0;
let y_position = 0;
// Timer variable
let timer = null;
function render() {
    // draw the character on the screen according to the current x_position and y_position
}
function onJump() {
    // If we're already jumping, we want to cancel the previous jump timeout so gravity suddenly doesn't double.
    if ( timer ) clearInterval( timer );
    // Set our current position to max jumping height.
    y_position = MAX_JUMP_HEIGHT;
    timer = setInterval( function() {
        // subtract one pixel from the the current position
        y_position--;
        // call a render function
        render();
        // Cancel the interval once we reach 0px jump height.
        if ( !y_position ) clearInterval( timer );
    }, 100 );
};
```

You can edit the numbers  a bit to get stuff like platforms to work, where 0px y_position will not always be the baseline and w want to use the MAX_HEIGHT as an offset per jump.

Comment: This is making the character jump, but they're not coming down. I'm not too sure why either.